# size of the tree, Not in scope

Tags: haskell, tree, count, scope

Here is my code:

```
data Binary_Tree a = Null 
                      |Node {element :: a, left_tree, right_tree :: Binary_Tree a}
   deriving (Show, Eq)

--depth_of_tree 

dot :: Integral b => Binary_Tree a -> b
dot Null = 0
dot Node (a left right) = 1 + (dot Node (a left right)) + (dot Node (a left right))
```

however, when i load it in ghci it, and input

```
dot Node (2 (Node 3 Null Null) Null)
```

it comes out an error:

```
<interactive>:13:1:
    Not in scope: `dot'
    Perhaps you meant `not' (imported from Prelude)
```

Anyone likes to tell me what's wrong with my code pls?

Thanks for anyone who can good me some advice XD

Answer (score 1):

1) Error on declaration (your code contains infinite recursion). Try this:

```
--depth_of_tree 
dot :: Integral b => Binary_Tree a -> b
dot Null = 0
dot (Node _ left right) = 1 + dot left + dot right
```

2) error with parentheses. Try this

```
  dot $ Node 2 (Node 3 Null Null) Null
```